# Display Blank with multiple functions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I currently have a formula Cell U22 "=SUMIF(N22:T22,"=X",M22)" where I can enter future income in a column N thru T. I mark an x in cell beside said number when I receive it and now the formula will add them together in Cell U22, but only the received amount.

I'm not sure how it works, but it does exactly what I need it to. If there are no numbers, then the value is 0.
If I have numbers but haven't "received" them yet, it will only add the received funds.

What I'm looking to do, is have this cell stay blank until I receive funds. I have tried changing the M22 part of the formula to relate to blank. It just comes back with error code. I've tried if u22=0 then display blank, if not, use formula.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is written in M22?

Comment: Kindly show some Data to be more clear

Comment: Mate was able to give me the correct answer. Thank you! M22 is sometimes blank, other times it is filled with a letter

Answer (score 0):

Adapt your formula like this:

`=IF (SUMIF(N22:T22,"=X",M22)=0,"",SUMIF(N22:T22,"=X",M22))`

Comment: You're the best!! I didn't think to do that. That worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm happy it solved your issue. Please don't forget to accept it.